# JSON issue in Spring 3 and

Tags: json, spring-mvc, extjs

I am using Spring 3.0 and ExtJS. I have been trying to send a Map object from my controller to jsp.  When I putting a pojo in `HashMap` and sending that `HashMap` to view.

From controller it is returning a `Map` but in ExtJS it is not able to read the response and gives below error.

```
HTTP Error code: 406
message 

description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers ().
```

Can anyone tell that how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can just shove any POJO into a map and return it via an HttpResponse.  That's not how JSON works.

In order to send JSON from Java, you have to do the equivalent of serializing it using a JSON API (or roll your own).  [FlexJSON](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/&ei=pY9oT4WEF-aKsALC_PGNCQ&usg=AFQjCNH7baOUHmr-OO1Y885txj4T-Uu1-Q&sig2=lXePBN8KFK1R2L7VKifeFA) is one I use, as it ships in Spring Roo and is pretty easy.

Comment: "I dont think you can just shove any POJO into a map and return it via an HttpResponse" - yes, you can.

Comment: I dont see how, but ok.  From [this](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html), an HTTP 406 is defined as the inability for the client to accept your message.  It states several possible causes: MIME type, Charset, Encoding, Language, and Ranges.  I would suggest capturing your request/response pairs and looking at the HTTP headers.  Odds are, you are sending back something the client doesn't like too much, and my guess is it's not JSON.